# If $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is compact then $X \times X \subset \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n$ is compact - proof verification

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, multivariable-calculus, compactness

Claim: If $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is compact, then $X \times X  \subset \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n$ is compact.

Key definitions:

- A set $X$ is closed if every convergence sequence converges to a point in the set $X$.
- A set $X$ is bounded if there exists $M > 0$ such that for all $x \in X$, $\|x\| < M$.
- A set $X$ is compact if it is closed and bounded.

Attempt:

i) bounded

Observe an element $(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}) \in X\times X$ can be written in the form  $(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}) = (x_1, \dots, x_n, y_{n+1}, \dots, y_{2n}) = (x_1, \dots, x_n, 0_{n+1}, \dots, 0_{2n}) + (0_1, \dots, 0_n, y_{n+1}, \dots, y_{2n})$. For conciseness I will use the bold form to represent the points. With this being the case we can write the following:

$$\|(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y})\| = \|(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{0}) + (\mathbf{0}, \mathbf{y})\| \leq \|(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{0})\| + \|(\mathbf{0}, \mathbf{y})\| < M + M = 2M$$

Therefore $X \times X$ is bounded.

ii) closed

Somewhat in the same vein we can consider the convergent sequences $\mathbf{x}_k \to \mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{y}_j \to \mathbf{b}$. and we will show we have the sequence $(\mathbf{x}_k, \mathbf{y}_j) \to (\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b}) \in X \times X$.

As the idea from boundedness, the sequence can be written out explicitly as $(\mathbf{x}_k, \mathbf{y}_j) = (x_k^1, x_k^2, \dots, x_k^n, y_j^{n+1}, y_j^{n+2}, \dots, y_j^{2n})$. Where the superscripts are the individual components and the subscripts represent the sequence for that component.  The same would occur for the point of convergence: $(\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b}) = (a_1, \dots, a_n, b_{n+1}, \dots, b_{2n})$. Continuing with the idea from the boundedness part I could then rewrite these with sets collections of zeroes. Thus I would have something of the form (using the bolded notation)

$$ (\mathbf{x}_k, \mathbf{y}_j) = (\mathbf{x}_k, \mathbf{0}) + (\mathbf{0}, \mathbf{y}_j)\\ (\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b}) = (\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{0}) + (\mathbf{0}, \mathbf{b})$$

Therefore I can do the following:

$$\|(\mathbf{x}_k, \mathbf{y}_j) - (\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b})\| = \|(\mathbf{x}_k, \mathbf{0}) + (\mathbf{0}, \mathbf{y}_j) - (\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{0}) + (\mathbf{0}, \mathbf{b})\| \\ \leq \|(\mathbf{x}_k, \mathbf{0}) - (\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{0})\| + \|(\mathbf{0}, \mathbf{y}_j) - (\mathbf{0}, \mathbf{b})\| $$

If we choose the greater of $K$ or $J$ from each of the sequences, then there exists $k$ or $j$ (whichever is larger) such that $\|\mathbf{x}_k - \mathbf{a}\| < \frac{\delta}{2}$ and  $\|\mathbf{y}_j - \mathbf{b}\| < \frac{\delta}{2}$. So we can apply this to the inequality above and thus:

$$ \|(\mathbf{x}_k, \mathbf{0}) - (\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{0})\| + \|(\mathbf{0}, \mathbf{y}_j) - (\mathbf{0}, \mathbf{b})\| < \frac{\delta}{2} + \frac{\delta}{2} = \delta$$.

And this proves the set is closed thus $X \times X$ is compact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your definition of closed isn't accurate

> A set $X$ is closed if every convergent sequence **of elements in X** converges to a point in the set $X$.

You wrote this:

> Somewhat in the same vein we can consider the convergent sequences $\mathbf{x}_k \to \mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{y}_j \to \mathbf{b}$. and we will show we have the sequence $(\mathbf{x}_k, \mathbf{y}_j) \to (\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b}) \in X \times X$.

This doesn't match with the definition of being closed !!!!!!  To prove that $X \times X $ is closed in $\mathbb  R^n \times \mathbb R ^n$ you have to do the opposite of what you just said. You must consider a sequences of elements $(x_n,y_n)$ in $X \times X$ which is convergent and show that its limit $\lim_{n \to \infty}(x_n,y_n) = (a,b)$ is a point in $X \times X$.

Assuming that $\lim_{n\to \infty}(x_n,y_n) = (a,b)$ then it is not hard to show that the sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ and $(y_n)_{n \in \mathbb N }$ converge to $a$ and $b$ respectively. To finish the proof you must then prove that $a \in X$ and $b \in X$ (you will use the fact that $X$ is closed to prove this).